# Why is my login script not running the checks as coded

Tags: php

I have two pages, index.php and login.php. index.php shows the login form and login.php contains the coding behind the login system. I have attached some of the coding for each page and explained my problem below.

index.php

```
<form id="loginForm" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">            
        <label>Email Address:</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" autofocus class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($form_token)); ?>" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">

    <?php echo $error ?>
    <?php echo $message ?>
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("../config.php");  

    if (array_key_exists('Submit', $_POST)) {
        $Valid = 1;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Email or Password is invalid</div>';
        }

        else {
            // Define $username and $password
            $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));

            // $password = md5(trim(stripslashes($_POST['password'])));
            $password = md5($password);

            // Check that the Username and Password and have been sent
            if(!isset( $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['form_token'])) {
                $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a valid Email Address and Password.</div>';
            }

            // Check if the form token is valid
            elseif( $_POST['form_token'] != $_SESSION['form_token']) {
                $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid submission.</div>';
            }

            try {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
                $stmt->execute(array($email, $password));       
            }

            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                $row['Username'];
            }           

            if ($stmt == 1) {
                $_SESSION['login_user'] = $email; // Initializing Session
                header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
            } 

            else {
                $conn = null; // Closing Connection
            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

I don't understand why $message does not write anything out to the page. $error is working fine, if email and password = blank, it'll write out "Email or Password is invalid". However, if you use an email and password that does not exist it'll redirect to profile.php but show this error:

```
This web page has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

What am I doing wrong?

profile.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('../session.php');
    include_once("../config.php");      

    if(!isset($login_session)) {
        $conn = null; // Closing Connection
        header('Location: /account/'); // Redirect to Home
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the validation you have in profile.php

Comment: I'll write that above.

Comment: Also, the action should be login.php or are you submitting via JavaScript ?

Comment: I'm including login.php at the top of index.php. I'll add it on the form action too.

Comment: Still have the same issue with it added to the action="" too.

Comment: What is this file (/account/) doing. Is it has redirection to profile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely stemming from this `if`:

```
if ($stmt == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $email; // Initializing Session
    header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}
```

I don't know why you thought the prepared statement would be equal to `1`. Either you're confused about how to check the status of the query, in which case you'll want to store the status of the execution, `$status = $stmt->execute(array($email, $password));`. See the PHP docs on [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), return value is `True` or `False`. Then check the status in the if: `if ($status) {`

You may also be attempting to verify that one and only one row is returned by your select. That's a bit trickier, as `PDOStatement::rowCount()` doesn't work with `SELECT` statements. You'll likely want something like: `if (count($stmt->fetchAll()) == 1) {`, first getting an array of rows returned, then counting them.